# Is it possible to place simple app with React and MobX within one html page?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I would like just link to libraries by src and use them without Node.JS or Webpack.

Comment: Please, mark an answer as accepted if your question was resolved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just use the service like unpkg:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/mobx@6.3.2/dist/mobx.umd.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/mobx-react@7.2.0/dist/mobxreact.umd.production.min.js"></script>
```

It will be available through `window.React`, `window.ReactDOM` and etc.